# Angular UI-Router : conditionally change anchor position on state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Angular UI Router v0.2.10 & Angular 1.2.6

I have created a Plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/HrGfNcuIv16rKp7GchVJ?p=preview

When a user changes `$state`, their scroll position stays wherever their current scroll position is. Sometimes, I want the user's scroll position to jump to the top of the page when the state change. For instance, if the user clicks on a link in a footer (see Plunkr), the new state should start at the top of the page.

**What is the best way to conditionally apply those that sort of rule on a state change?**

Answer (score 0):

Create a scroll to top directive that you apply to the container. Basically allow a value to pass in, which when changed will scroll the directive element to top:

```
<div class="myContainer" scrollToTop="someScopeVar"></div>
```

Then watch for state changes, and set the value on the directive to enforce a scroll to the top of the page.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    $scope.someScopeVar = !$scope.someScopeVar;
});
```

Comment: So how would you pass in a value to `someScopeVar` when changing `$state`?

Comment: Just flip it as I did above (in the state change event). Then inside the directive, put a `$watch` on the value.